# Limit of a product of trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to find the following limit:
$$J=\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^N \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{k^2}\right).$$
How can I calculate it?
Thanks

Comment: is it $(-1/ \sqrt{2})$

Comment: @Vikram It can't be that because the product of the first two factors is $(-1/ \sqrt{2})$, and each additional factor is between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: as N increases from 3 to $\infty$, the bracket term approaches zero, so cos() approaches 1, so it is $(-1)(1/ \sqrt{2})(1)$

Comment: @Vikram Well, let's consider the product of the first three factors then, and apply your logic to the factors after those. As N increases from 4 to $/infty$, the bracket term approaches zero, so cos() approaches 1, so it is $(-1)(1/ \sqrt{2})(\cos(\frac{\pi}{9}))(1)$. Contradiction.

Comment: @Vikram since \cos approaches $1$ (but never reaches it), the product will be strictly smaller (in absolute value) than $1/\sqrt{2}$. My gut feeling is that there is no *nice* closed-form expression for this infinite product (Wolfram Alpha didn't find one either). The approximate value of the product is $-0.6402929927485\ldots$

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra please give me feedback on my answer.

Comment: Did you get it?????